# modprobe nvidia throws error: could not insert 'off'

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, bumblebee, modprobe

I am trying to configure bumblebee to switch my nvidia discrete card. As well bumblebee crashes when tries to modprobe nvidia. When i try to do it manually, i face the same error:

```
$ modprobe nvidia

modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:832 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='off'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'off': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Nvidia driver version is 410, when using 390 i face the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `nvidia-prime`? And then switch cards using the Nvidia X Server Settings? Bumblebee is outdated, I think.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I would use it, but it doesn't turn my discrete card off. Earlier I used bumblebee to shut down discrete card, and had success, but I've tried to update my nvidia drivers which broke everyhting. So my only choice is to use bumblebee.

Comment: You're supposed to reboot after setting a different card. Did you? (I know, we don't have to in Windows, but I'm telling you how it is in Ubuntu/Linux)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Yes, of course I did. I also had problems with that (login screen freeze), but there was a problem with ACPI tables. Now i can `prime-select` but my discrete card stays ON always, which doubles up my power discharge.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So, IMHO, nvidia did some changes to their install. For everyone trying to get bumblebee work with their nvidia driver, you have to know that:

1. Now nvidia library is located in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`
2. `blacklist-nvidia.conf` file is located in `/lib/modprobe.d/`

The answer was in `blacklist-nvidia.conf`, which still had `alias nvidia off` uncommented.

Comment: Confirmed to work in 18.04 after upgrade to nvidia 390.77. Bumblebee works for me now.

Comment: I'm not using bumblebee but my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop stopped loading the nvidia driver and `sudo modprobe -v nvidia` had the same error message as in this question. Commenting out the `alias nvidia off` in `blacklist-nvidia.conf` fixed it for me.